# .include? returns false while I would expect true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my seeds file I have the line:

```
@organization.relationships.include?(@user)
```

Although this line should be `true`, it is `false`. Does anyone understand why, given the following output from the `debugger`?

```
(byebug) @organization.relationships
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Relationship id: 2, user_id: 2, organization_id: 2, member: true, ..., updated_at: "2015-08-01 19:44:54">]>
(byebug) @user.id
2
(byebug) @organization.relationships.include?(@user)
false
```

In the debugger `@organization.relationship` proofs that `user` with `id=2` is included in the organization's relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@organization.relationships` doesn't contain `users` instances it's contain `relation` instances between `user` and `organization`(I assume you use [`HABTM`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)).You can use [`where`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) to find user id in `relationships`.

```
=> @organization.relationships.where(user_id: @user.id).any?
#> true 
#> short version should work too.
=> @organization.relationships.where(user: @user).any?
```

You able to use [`where`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) here because it's `<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`. Ref for [`any?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/any%3F)

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare `@user` to `User` objects not `Relationship` objects

```
@organization.relationships.map(&:user).include?(@user)
```

Answer (score 1):

This line below will return you the relatioships for particular organization.

```
@organization.relationships
```

Now what you are currently doing is trying to see if user exists in the active record relation list of relationships which you will always get false.

if you want to see the user present for the relationships associated to organization. you should do this.

```
@organization.relationships.collect(&:user).compact.include?(@user)
```

This way what you will do is fetch relationships for the organization and then user associated for the relationships. and match the user.